# Error in Jframe: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, mysql, database, erd

I am trying to put multiple rows in `productorder` table with the same foreign key which is the `order_id` from `orders` table but this error is keep showing:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MYSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException
>   Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   ('store', 'productorder', CONSTRAINT 'productorder_ibfk_1', FOREIGN
>   KEY ('order_id'), REFERENCES 'orders' ('order_id'))

Here is my code:

```
 private void SUBMIT1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  try{
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/homemade","root", "");

        String sql3 = "insert into productorder(order_id, prod_id, quantity, subtotal_price) values (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ?, ?, ?)";
        String sql4 = "SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM orders ";
        PreparedStatement pst3 = conn.prepareStatement(sql3);
        PreparedStatement pst4 = conn.prepareStatement(sql4);
        String sql5 = "insert into productorder(order_id, prod_id, quantity, subtotal_price) values (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ?, ?, ?)";
        String sql6 = "SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM orders ";
        PreparedStatement pst5 = conn.prepareStatement(sql5);
        PreparedStatement pst6 = conn.prepareStatement(sql6);
        String sql7 = "insert into productorder(order_id, prod_id, quantity, subtotal_price) values (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ?, ?, ?)";
        String sql8 = "SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM orders ";
        PreparedStatement pst7 = conn.prepareStatement(sql7);
        PreparedStatement pst8 = conn.prepareStatement(sql8);
        String sql9 = "insert into productorder(order_id, prod_id, quantity, subtotal_price) values (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ?, ?, ?)";
        String sql10 = "SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM orders ";
        PreparedStatement pst9 = conn.prepareStatement(sql9);
        PreparedStatement pst10 = conn.prepareStatement(sql10);
        String sql11 = "insert into productorder(order_id, prod_id, quantity, subtotal_price) values (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ?, ?, ?)";
        String sql12 = "SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM orders ";
        PreparedStatement pst11 = conn.prepareStatement(sql11);
        PreparedStatement pst12 = conn.prepareStatement(sql12);
        String sql13 = "insert into productorder(order_id, prod_id, quantity, subtotal_price) values (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ?, ?, ?)";
        String sql14 = "SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM orders ";
        PreparedStatement pst13 = conn.prepareStatement(sql13);
        PreparedStatement pst14 = conn.prepareStatement(sql14); 

    if(shanghai1.isSelected() == true){
       pst3.setString(1, "4");
       pst3.setString(2, shangqua.getText());
       pst3.setString(3, subShang1.getText());
       pst3.executeUpdate();
       pst4.executeQuery();
   }




    if(siomai1.isSelected() == true){
       pst5.setString(1, "5"); 
       pst5.setString(2, sioqua.getText());
       pst5.setString(3, subSiomai1.getText());
       pst5.executeUpdate();
       pst6.executeQuery();
    }



    if(burger1.isSelected() == true){
       pst7.setString(1, "1"); 
       pst7.setString(2, burqua.getText());
       pst7.setString(3, subBurger1.getText());
       pst7.executeUpdate();
       pst8.executeQuery(); 

    }



    if(embotido1.isSelected() == true){
       pst9.setString(1, "2");  
       pst9.setString(2, embqua.getText());
       pst9.setString(3, subEmbotido1.getText());
       pst9.executeUpdate();
       pst10.executeQuery();
    }


    if(skinless1.isSelected() == true){
       pst11.setString(1, "6"); 
       pst11.setString(2, skiqua.getText());
       pst11.setString(3, subSkinless1.getText());
       pst11.executeUpdate();
       pst12.executeQuery();
    }


    if(nuggets1.isSelected() == true){
        pst13.setString(1, "3"); 
        pst13.setString(2, nugqua.getText());
        pst13.setString(3, subNuggets1.getText());
        pst13.executeUpdate();
        pst14.executeQuery();
    }


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record updated successfully!");



    }
   catch(Exception e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }
```

and here is the table diagram:

[Table diagram image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFs3U.jpg)

Comment: what is the LAST_INSERT_ID() function that you are using?

Comment: I was trying to get the last inserted primary ID from orders table to use it as a foreign key to productorder table.

Comment: I can guess what it trying to do by looking the function name. Since the error is saying that the constraint foreign key is violating, then it might from the order id that you're trying to populate - wrong or null. So it would help that you also post that function / procedure LAST_INSERT_ID() for further troubleshooting.